# Woocommerce How to Show Related Categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Good Day, I have the following Code Snippet to help me add custom columns to a plugin the first bit works perfectly but now I would like to add Related Categories to the content (All of this works only in the admin panel) so no shortcode will work

```
// ADD CUSTOM COLUMN
if( !function_exists('yith_wcbep_add_columns') ) {
 function yith_wcbep_add_columns( $columns ) {

 $columns['new_column'] = 'Related Categories';

 return $columns;
 }

   add_filter( 'yith_wcbep_default_columns', 'yith_wcbep_add_columns', 99 );
}
```

this snipped added content to the columns

```
// ADD CONTECT TO CUSTOM COLUMN
if( !function_exists('yith_wcbep_manage_custom_columns_add_columns_to_new_column') ) {
 function yith_wcbep_manage_custom_columns_add_columns_to_new_column( $value, $column_name, $post ) {

 if ( 'new_column' == $column_name ) {
 $value = 'Custom value'; // This shows the value as Custom value
 }

 return $value;
 }

   add_filter( 'yith_wcbep_manage_custom_columns', 'yith_wcbep_manage_custom_columns_add_columns_to_new_column', 10, 3 );
}
```

as soon as I add this code everything disappears from the columns, this code goes where the Custom value is at

```
$terms = get_the_terms($product->ID, 'product_cat');
      foreach ($terms as $term) {

        echo $product_cat = $term->name.', ';
  }
```

**UPDATE**

```
if( !function_exists('yith_wcbep_manage_custom_columns_add_columns_to_new_column') ) {
    
 function yith_wcbep_manage_custom_columns_add_columns_to_new_column( $value, $column_name, $post ) {

 if ( 'also_column' == $column_name ) {
     $prod_cat_args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat', //woocommerce
  'orderby'      => 'name',
  'empty'        => 0
);

//$woo_categories = get_categories( $prod_cat_args );
$woo_categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

foreach ( $woo_categories as $woo_cat ) {
    $woo_cat_id = $woo_cat->term_id; //category ID
    $woo_cat_name = $woo_cat->name; //category name
$my_query = "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_termmeta WHERE term_id='$woo_cat_id' AND meta_key=\'crosssell\'";
     foreach ($my_query as $row) {
 //$value =  'Test - '.$woo_cat->term_id.' - '.$woo_cat->name;
 $value =  'Test - '.$row->meta_value;
     }
   
}
 
 }
 return $value;
 }
```

but the result keeps being blank, what I'm I doing wrong? if I take out the $my_query section it shows the category and ID but I need to get the CROSSSELL CATEGORY

**UPDATED 2 This is the Whole Code**

```
// ADD CUSTOM COLUMN
if( !function_exists('yith_wcbep_add_columns') ) {
 function yith_wcbep_add_columns( $columns ) {
 $columns['also_column'] = 'Also See...';

 return $columns;
 }

   add_filter( 'yith_wcbep_default_columns', 'yith_wcbep_add_columns', 99 );
}
// ADD CONTECT TO CUSTOM COLUMN
if( !function_exists('yith_wcbep_manage_custom_columns_add_columns_to_new_column') ) {
    
 function yith_wcbep_manage_custom_columns_add_columns_to_new_column( $value, $column_name, $post ) {

 if ( 'also_column' == $column_name ) {
     $prod_cat_args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat', //woocommerce
  'orderby'      => 'name',
  'empty'        => 0
);

//$woo_categories = get_categories( $prod_cat_args );
$woo_categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

foreach ( $woo_categories as $woo_cat ) {
    $woo_cat_id = $woo_cat->term_id; //category ID
    $woo_cat_name = $woo_cat->name; //category name
$my_query = "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_termmeta WHERE term_id='$woo_cat_id' AND meta_key=\'crosssell\'";
     foreach ($my_query as $row) {
 //$value =  'Test - '.$woo_cat->term_id.' - '.$woo_cat->name;
 $value =  'Test - '.$row->meta_value;
     }
   
}
 
 }
 return $value;
 }
add_filter( 'yith_wcbep_manage_custom_columns', 'yith_wcbep_manage_custom_columns_add_columns_to_new_column', 10, 3 );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after very a long time I got this to work

```
**$product = wc_get_product($post);
     $categories = strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat', '', ',', '' ));
 
 /*End*/
     $value = $categories;**
```

it shows the categories as it should I added strip_tags to remove the links so now only text remains.

But Now I ran into another problem I cannot get crosssell to show up even if it is there

```
foreach((get_term_meta( $post->ID, 'crosssell' )) as $category) {
$cat_name = $category->name . '</br>';
$cat_id = $category->term_id . '</br>';
$crosssell = get_term_meta( $cat_id, 'crosssell', true );
}
```

can display $cat_name and $cat_id no problem but the $crosssell does not display at all

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following.

```
$terms = get_the_terms($product->ID, 'product_cat');
$categories = '';
  foreach ($terms as $term) {

    $categories .= $product_cat = $term->name.', ';
}
return $categories;
```

But sill there might some question, in function you used post as parameter, but you use product in this.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, I get the following Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\code-snippets\php\snippet-ops.php(469) : eval()'d code on line 23

Comment: get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
you can try with post rather than product. there might be an problem with this. if possible share the whole code.

Comment: I have added the whole code to the original question under UPDATED 2 This is the Whole Code